# What does "loss of wellbeing" mean in context

Tags: meaning

> The economic impact of asthma was estimated to be 300 dollars. 100 dollars were attributed to financial cost, and 200 dollars were attributed to loss of wellbeing.

What does "loss of wellbeing" mean here?

Why is "loss of wellbeing" related to the "cost"?

Comment: Loss in quality of life

Comment: Medical insurance companies might well compensate clients for suffering/disabilities such as the impact of asthma on their lives.

Comment: It means "feeling unwell", basically.

Comment: Liquidated damages for the stress of asthma attacks,  being unable to participate in activities,  etc.

Comment: @RonaldSole Most medical insurance policies would not cover the insured (asthma sufferer) for consequential losses such as pain, SUFFERING (my emphasis) and loss of amenity or to compensate for the impact of asthma on a sufferer's life

Comment: Although in this case it probably isn't necessary to answer, it is customary to cite your source, to link to or least name the place where you read this quote.

Comment: @PeterPoint http://insurance.healthadvisor.com/national/pre-existing-conditions/asthma/   http://www.staysure.co.uk/travel-insurance/asthma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "loss of "wellbeing" in the context of an asthma sufferer's health is an another way of stating that such a person is not in a healthy state, wellbeing being another way of referring to a person's good health in this context. Since the economic loss suffered by the asthma sufferer is stated to be $200, we must assume that this is an enumeration of the economic loss that he/she has suffered from loss of income (perhaps the person has been unable to do his/her job), with incidental expenses of an asthmatic condition amounting to, in this example, a financial loss of $100.

Is the OP sure that these amounts are not $200 million and $100 million respectively, in which case we are dealing with the US economic consequences of asthma at State or Federal level?

Comment: Wellbeing or well-being: the satisfactory state that someone...should be in, that involves  such things as being happy, HEALTHY [my emphasis] and safe, and having enough money (macmillandictionary.com)

Comment: Hi Peter, another question is why doesn't people include the cost of well-being in financial cost?@Peter Point

Answer (score 1):

*Wellbeing* (more commonly spelt *well-being*) is defined as “*[A state of health, happiness and/or prosperity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/well-being)*”.

I imagine that what the author means is that someone who suffers from asthma loses an average of 200 dollars (per month?) due to being unable to work properly or at all when suffering from asthma attacks.